# How to unify Date & Time format when there inconsistency exists across a single column

Tags: r, date, time, unify

I am working on a data frame that has a column that uses the date and time format as "mm/dd/yy HH:MM" for some observations and "yyyy/mm/dd HH:MM:SS" format for other observations, of course, this inconsistency results in errors or NA returns in my code, how can I unify the whole column so my calculations are not interrupted by this inconsistency?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dcmQ.png)

Comment: Convert them into `date` format with `as.Date()`

Comment: @TomHoel

i am using this line but the results is a column with all NA values mutate(start_date_corrected=as.Date(started_at, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"))

Comment: Can you share a sample of your data by using `dput(your_data)` ?

Comment: @shafee it is available in the embedded pic click on (enter image description here)

Comment: Its always a good idea to provide a sample of the data, so that we can help you. Providing a screenshot of the data is not helpful. If you are not being helpful, its a bit difficult for us to help you. : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update step by step:

1. We have a data frame with for columns each of them have character type columns (you can check this with `str(df)`
2. In order to change the format from character to datetime in all four columns we use `mutate(across(1:4, ...`
3. What we want is that in each column 1:4 the character type is changed to datetime
4. this can be done with the function `parse_date_time` from lubridate package
5. Here we use `~` to indicate an anonymous function
6. the `.` indicates column 1-4.
7. and most important the argument `c("ymd_HMS", "mdy_HM")`  which gives the order of the different formats of the date columns!

We could use `parse_date_time()` from `lubridate` package. Important is the argument `c("ymd_HMS", "mdy_HM")`. Here you define the occurence of the different formats:

and note to use `HMS` , because:

```
hms, hm and ms usage is defunct, please use HMS, HM or MS instead. Deprecated in version '1.5.6'.
```

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(1:4, ~parse_date_time(., c("ymd_HMS", "mdy_HM"))))
```

```
  started_at          ended_at            started_at_1        ended_at_1         
  <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>             
1 2021-10-29 17:42:36 2021-10-29 18:00:23 2021-06-13 11:40:00 2021-06-13 12:02:00
2 2021-10-01 15:06:10 2021-10-01 15:09:23 2021-06-27 16:26:00 2021-06-27 16:39:00
3 2021-10-28 23:02:53 2021-10-28 23:07:11 2021-06-10 20:06:00 2021-06-10 20:28:00
4 2021-10-17 00:58:17 2021-10-17 01:02:08 2021-06-11 15:54:00 2021-06-11 16:11:00
5 2021-10-27 18:29:34 2021-10-27 18:34:48 2021-06-05 14:09:00 2021-06-05 14:42:00
6 2021-10-17 13:30:21 2021-10-17 13:35:26 2021-06-05 14:14:00 2021-06-05 14:37:00
7 2021-10-04 19:59:28 2021-10-04 21:06:24 2021-06-16 19:05:00 2021-06-16 19:16:00
8 2021-10-10 00:27:09 2021-10-10 00:39:58 2021-06-23 20:29:00 2021-06-23 20:43:00
```

data:

```
structure(list(started_at = c("2021-10-29 17:42:36", "2021-10-01 15:06:10", 
"2021-10-28 23:02:53", "2021-10-17 00:58:17", "2021-10-27 18:29:34", 
"2021-10-17 13:30:21", "2021-10-04 19:59:28", "2021-10-10 00:27:09"
), ended_at = c("2021-10-29 18:00:23", "2021-10-01 15:09:23", 
"2021-10-28 23:07:11", "2021-10-17 01:02:08", "2021-10-27 18:34:48", 
"2021-10-17 13:35:26", "2021-10-04 21:06:24", "2021-10-10 00:39:58"
), started_at_1 = c("6/13/21 11:40", "6/27/21 16:26", "6/10/21 20:06", 
"6/11/21 15:54", "6/5/21  14:09", "6/5/21  14:14", "6/16/21 19:05", 
"6/23/21 20:29"), ended_at_1 = c("6/13/21 12:02", "6/27/21 16:39", 
"6/10/21 20:28", "6/11/21 16:11", "6/5/21  14:42", "6/5/21  14:37", 
"6/16/21 19:16", "6/23/21 20:43")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: hello, can you walk me here step by step ?

Comment: A bit irrelevant to the question, Can you guide how did you manage to read that data from that image? @TarJae

Comment: @admo7000 Please see my update!

Comment: @TarJae Thank you for you effort and time to explain further

Comment: @TarJae This works now and i have successfully unified my format across the column